# How to upload screenshot to Facebook in cocos2d-x 2.x on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I've search but didn't find a solution to upload screenshot to Facebook on iOS

In cocos2d-x, gamescene.cpp :

```
void GameScene::takeScreenshot()
{
    SoundManager::getInstance()->playSound("sound2.mp3");
    CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    CCRenderTexture* texture = CCRenderTexture::create((int)size.width, (int)size.height);
    texture->setPosition(ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2));
    texture->begin();
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()->visit();
    texture->end();
    texture->saveToFile("screenshot.png", kCCImageFormatPNG);

    Link::postToFacebook();

}
```

in Link:postToFacebook function :

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.jinibot.com"]];
//        [controller addImage:image];
        [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"screenshot.png"]];


        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        //add as many images as you want
//        [controller presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Help me please. Thank you !

Comment: First see that your take screen shot method give you screen shot or not?? If it's give you screen shot then it's problem some where in Your fb sharing method.

Comment: It gave me screenshot. And I don't know how to get that screenshot and share it FB.

Comment: Set return type of ScreenShot method as UIImage. And While Share image With FB Call that method. Feel free for help if you need more help regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is

```
[controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"screenshot.png"]];
```

This method

```
texture->saveToFile("screenshot.png", kCCImageFormatPNG);
```

saves image in Documents Directory, but here you are using image as bundle image which can not be retrieved.
So create `UIImage` Object from `NSDocuments` directory path.
The code will work fine. :)